# Display mysql data in php function

Tags: php, mysql, function

Ok i got a problem now i want to display a data from the database and display it through a function now how do i do that??

like i have fetched a row from the database and its name is $row_field['data']; and it is correct now i have assigned a variable to it like this $data = $row_field['data']; now if i call it in a function it shows undefined variable even after i assigned it global in the function like this

```
function fun(){
    global $data;
    echo $data;
}
```

but if i assign it a value like 1 or 2 or anything it gets displayed without any error why is that so??

Comment: Please show a full code example

Comment: uff... I dont now where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it displays if you assign it a value like 1 or 2 while still in the global scope, then I can only assume that your database did not return the result you thought it did.  Does the database value display if you echo it out outside of the function?

Answer (score 0):

Global is evil. I dont know what you are trying to do, but why dont you just do the query in the function itself?

Comment: Damn this is really embarrassing please forgive to waste your time its worked i missed the "l" in global that's why it was giving error thank you TJ for your time..

Answer (score 0):

If you have a column named `data` and your php call was something like

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT data FROM mytable");

while ($row_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    ...  
}
```

Then you could replace `...` with `print $row_field['data']`.

Else please provide a snippet of your code where you query the db and retrieve the result.

Comment: Once again sorry nyom my bad.. :p

Answer (score 0):

When learning php try to start with simple things. For example in order to get some data from a database follow the [examples](http://no.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) from php website.

```
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");

if (!$conn) {
    echo "Unable to connect to DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (!mysql_select_db("mydbname")) {
    echo "Unable to select mydbname: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

$sql = "SELECT id as userid, fullname, userstatus 
    FROM   sometable
    WHERE  userstatus = 1";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) {
    echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
    exit;
}

// While a row of data exists, put that row in $row as an associative array
// Note: If you're expecting just one row, no need to use a loop
// Note: If you put extract($row); inside the following loop, you'll
//       then create $userid, $fullname, and $userstatus
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["userid"];
    echo $row["fullname"];
    echo $row["userstatus"];
}

mysql_free_result($result);
```

If all this goes well go a little further change a little the while loop.

```
$myArray = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $myArray[] = $row;
}

mysql_free_result($result);

// now you can start playing with your data
echo $myArray[0];
```

Small steps...